# How to know where page is scrolled in Selenium IDE?

Tags: automated-testing, selenium-ide

I have a page which has links that used `onclick="gotoLocation"` to scroll to an element elsewhere on the page.

I know I can use `storeElementPositionLeft` and `storeElementPositionTop` to get the element's position (and manually scroll to it through `storeEval` and `scrollTo`), but how do I confirm that the page has actually scrolled to the element or not?

We are using Selenium IDE (not Webdriver).

Comment: I would try seeing if the element is `visible`

Answer (score 1):

> but how do I confirm that the page has actually scrolled to the element or not?

If you use the [Kantu](https://github.com/A9T9/Kantu) [Selenium IDE](https://a9t9.com/kantu/docs/visual-ui-testing)'s [visual ui testing](https://a9t9.com/kantu/docs/visual-ui-testing) feature, you can use its `VisualAssert` command. As the name suggests, it compares an image (screenshot) of the element with whatever is on the browser screen when the test is run:

- if the image is found => test passed
- if the image is not found => test failed

In this use case, the default search are of [viewport](https://a9t9.com/kantu/docs/visual-ui-testing#visionlimitsearcharea) works just right for you.

Answer (score 0):

Use selenium to check the elements visibility

The element may exist but if not visible, this will show that.
If the element is present but not visible it can show that.

You can use `WebElement.isDisplayed()`

Be aware though that an element needs to be both visible **and** enabled, i.e.

```
public bool IsElementVisible(IWebElement element)
{
    return element.Displayed && element.Enabled;
}
```

JavascriptExecutor je = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
        // now execute query which actually will scroll until that element is not appeared on page.
        je.executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView("@id"));